# How to annotate multiple tags to single word over brat annotation tool?

Tags: nlp, brat

I want to annotate multiple entity's tags to single word.

In brat's example about ["the Colorado Richly Annotated Full Text Corpus (CRAFT)"](http://brat.nlplab.org/img/examples/CRAFT-16507151-full.png), a word "Collagen" is annotated by multiple tags such as "RR" and "GC CC".

Now, I try to annotate multiple entity's tags to single word, but brat says error with

> "AnnotationError: Error [LABEL A] cannot have identical span with
>   [LABEL B] T[X]"

message.

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

Note `<OVERLAP>` section in [advanced relations configuration](http://brat.nlplab.org/configuration.html#advanced-relations). If you want to disable overlap checking (i.e. allow for any overlap), you can use:

```
[relations]
<OVERLAP>   Arg1:<ENTITY>, Arg2:<ENTITY>, <OVL-TYPE>:<ANY>
```